# Discord.py detect when user disconnects bot from voice

Tags: python, discord.py

I have a bot that automatically connects when someone joins a voice channel, and disconnects when they're the last one in the voice channel.

It accomplishes this by checking the voice channels in the server using `on_voice_state_update` event.

But when a user disconnects the bot manually, it causes its voice state to update and then it immediately reconnects.

Is there a way to check if a user disconnected the bot manually (By right clicking > disconnect on the bot in the voice channel)?

Comment: One simple way is to have a file. Check if the value in the file is empty. If so, the prg gracefully completed. If not it was terminated. After you check write something into the file and close it. On gracefully shutting down, open file, delete whats in it, close file and close app.

Comment: @JoeFerndz I don't mean disconnect from discord alltogether, I mean when someone disconnects it from a voice channel.  (What would show up in the audit log as 'USER disconnected 1 user from voice')

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a old question but if someone needs it, you can detect if the bot itself has been disconnected by doing the following.

```py
@client.event
async def on_voice_state_update(member, before, after):
    if after.channel is None and member==client.user:
        print("Bot has been Disconnected")
```

This code check if the bot is in any voice channel after the voice state change and executes the print statement, it cannot detect if it was forcibly removed but it will be called when the bot is forcibly removed or simple disconnected using code.